# Utilizando WebService + SQLite

Tags: android, web-service, sqlite

Minha duvida é a seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que tem um acesso a um WebService, porem eu penso ser importante salvar alguns dados internos no aplicativo, como por exemplo, se o cara fizer login porem não tiver internet ele inutiliza o aplicativo, por isso preciso fazer com que quando o cara tiver online ele pegue toda informação nova no WebService e adiciona no SQLite, porem preciso também quando ele ficar online se caso tiver novas coisas no SQLite ele atualiza no WebService.

Um exemplo para entender, tem uma lista de alunos de curso de informática, e faço a chamada por meio de um aplicativo por meio de WebService, só que a internet caiu, porem preciso mesmo assim fazer a chamada, ok. Fiz a chamada, porem quando eu estiver na internet, preciso que essa chamada feita seja enviada para o servidor WebService, para que os donos da escola vejam. (É apenas um exemplo).

Como fazer isto ? Existe algum tutorial que me ensina algo parecido ? Qual a direção de estudos preciso ir para fazer isto ? Quais os métodos ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na `wikipédia` no que se refere a um `WEBSERVICE` pode-se ler:

> Web service é uma solução utilizada na integração de sistemas e na
>   comunicação entre aplicações diferentes.

Sendo que no seu caso as aplicações comunicam com um serviço online 'internet' então e respondendo diretamente a uma das suas dúvidas, se não houver comunicações os aplicativos não poderão comunicar.

Dito isto, é relevante também dizer que pode garantir algum tempo de falta de comunicação mantendo algumas funcionalidades de um aplicativo que não dependam do serviço online, ou então construir o aplicativo que consiga lidar com o *offline* realizando uma `POOL` de registos que mais tarde serão enviados.

As técnicas são várias dependendo da implementação e da situação. Refere ainda o `SQLITE`, este pode por exemplo ir registando alguma actividade e quando a aplicação deteta o *online* então realizar processos que sincronizem com o `WEBSERVICE`.

Comment: Hmm, então devo estudar mais sobre o pool e as possibilidades do sqlite ?